# zabbix monit switch,want to get interface 0/1's total traffic

Tags: linux, zabbix

[image: zabbix formula]

but the graph show me the data is incorrect.like this

[image: data]

My idea is to show the  Incoming traffic,  Outgoing traffic, total traffic, but I found that the total flow of data is incorrect, how to do?

Comment: In the calculated item, you probably need to use "Store value" with "As is", rather than "Delta (speed per second)".

Comment: Thank you.You're right,I have changed it,but sometimes i find that toal value is less than one of the other two  values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now,I get one way to solve this question.
e.g. Get total traffic on sw interface 0/1
chose TYPE Calculated
Formula: `last(ifHCInOctets["1"])+last(ifHCOutOctets["1"])`
ifHCInOctets["1"] this key value determined by your seeting
other:default